# Mapping List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> from web service to angular

Tags: angular

i have to call a service to get data which returns a type of keyvaluepair list

```
    Task<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> GetItems();
```

How do i map this, if let say i have a service in angular that calls this api ?

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize a List< KeyValuePair > object to json, you will see the an array like in the following;

```
[
    {
        "Key":"string",
        "Value":"string"
    },
    {
        "Key":"string",
        "Value":"string"
    }
]
```

You can parse this in the AngularJS Service like this;

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("welcome.htm").then(function (response) {
        var key1 = response.data[0].key;
        var value1 = response.data[0].value;
    });
});
```

Comment: if i create an object having properties of Key and Value for say, and i assign this directly to the response, will it automatically be mapped?



         
   this.myService.getKeyValueItems().subscribe((monthList) => {
      this.keyValueObject = monthList;
    });

im working with angular 4 btw..